# MS Word monospace font is not monospace for spaces

Tags: ms-word

I want to create a report including c++ source codes
with MS Word.

Though I use monospaced font Menlo, white spaces are not monospaced.

How to write C++ source codes with space indentation.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This looks to me like a bug, I'd take send this feedback to MS-Support. For future reference, this is more of a question for https://superuser.com/ than stackoverflow as it is only tangentially related to programming. But even there you will not find many representatives from MS-Word who'd be able to fix this bug.

Comment: Menlo is not a Microsoft font - it's a long-superseded Mac font that was replaced by SF Mono as of Mac OS 10.11, released on September 30, 2015.

Comment: I am aware of this (Menlo being a Mac Font), but the problem apparently appears in MS Word, that is why'd I'd bring it up there, I have not used menlo font myself.

Comment: The problem is unlikely to be with Word but with the font itself. After all, Word handles other monospaced fonts quite well.

Comment: I tried other monospaced fonts such as Andale Mono, Monaco, and Roboto Mono but they don't work. Fonts provided by Microsoft such as MingLiU and MS Mincho works but they look not good for codes.

Comment: Interesting, that seems to me that somehow the fonts are missing whitespace width definitions or ms word is not reading them properly, perhaps this will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/develop/character-design-standards/whitespace  

The obvious question that i've been keeping back from my tounge is why use word for writting code anyways? If you care a lot about typesetting, maybe LaTeX is an option?

Comment: Have you opened the font in a font editor such like font-forge to see if the space is the same width as the characters?

Comment: I opened Menlo.ttf with font forge and found space (0x20) has the same width as alphabets but it is larger than 1024 (1/2 em). Microsoft insists the maximum width should be no greater than 1/2 the em. That may cause this problem, I think.

Comment: LaTeX is a good option but, I'd like to fit contents in a single paper so WYSIWYG is better this time.

Comment: Fair enough, hopefully you'll find a font that fits your liking.